# Error when using KNeighborsClassifier using sklearn

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am doing KNN classification for a dataset of 28 features and 5000 samples:

```
trainingSet = []
testSet = []
imdb_score = range(1,11)

print ("Start splitting the dataset ...")
splitDataset(path + 'movies.csv', 0.60, trainingSet, testSet)

print ("Start KNeighborsClassifier ... \n")
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
neigh.fit(trainingSet, imdb_score)
```

However, I ran into this error:

```
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3362, 10]
```

I think my code looks alright. Kindly, has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got 6000 samples, use 60% of these, resulting in 3362 samples (as it seems, i don't seed your exact calculations).

You call `fit(X,Y)` [where the following is needed](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier):

- `y : {array-like, sparse matrix}`
- `Target values of shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]`

As your `y=imdb_score` is just a list of 10 values, neither of these rules apply as it needs to be either an array-like data-structure (list would be okay) with 3362 values or an array of shape `(3362, 1)`.

Comment: I am sorry It was a typo mistake. It is 5000 samples.